# How does .self work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, module, self, enumerable

I'm trying to re-write enumerable methods just for practice. I do not understand how `self` works in my methods. I know how to use it and what it returns, but what does `self` refer to?

Here's a sample of the `each` method I re-wrote to extend the `Enumerable` method [sic].

```
module Enumerable
  def my_each
    return self unless block_given?
    i = 0
    while i < self.length
      yield(self[i])
      i+=1
    end
  end
end
```

If someone can clarify how `self` works, I'd appreciate it. More specifically, I would like to know what `self.length` refers to and what role it plays in my code.

Comment: This is a very big question. It seems doubtful to me that a reader could provide a better explanation than is given in any Ruby book or essay on `self`. Neither is it a good use of readers' time when excellent explanations are available within easy reach.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, you have objects that you can send messages to. The object you send a message to is called the "receiver" of that message. Calling a method on an object basically just sends a message with the method's name to that object.

`self` is a Ruby language construct which refers to whatever the current receiver is. So, when you mix the Enumerable module into a class, then instantiate the class and call `#my_each` on it, the receiver will be an instance of that class, which you can get a handle to with the keyword `self`.

Comment: i want ur help regarding nokogiri